# Python calendar alignment

Tags: python, tkinter, calendar

When I run the code, the calendar day numbers do not align up with the week day they go with. I have tried justify = LEFT and RIGHT and CENTRE. None of these solve my problem even when not having the justify statement it doesn't work

```
from tkinter import *
import calendar as cl
import datetime as datet

year = int(datet.date.today().strftime("%Y")) #year
month =  int(datet.date.today().strftime("%m")) #month number

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

cal = Label(app, text = cl.month(year, month), justify = RIGHT)
cal.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tkinter is using a non-monospace font by default for Label. `calendar.month(year, month)` is one long string, which if you print in your console will come out as you intend. Change your code to be like so:

```
import calendar
import datetime
from tkinter import *

year = int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y"))  # year
month = int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%m"))  # month number

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

cal = Label(app, text=calendar.month(year, month), font=('Consolas', 12))
cal.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Consolas is a monospace font, there are other options aswell.

Note that if you instead broke up each part of the calendar into its own widget you wouldn't have to change the font to get them to align as you'd like.